# AWS S3 Boto3 Python - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am having a problem implementing delete_object.

```
def delete_image_from_s3(img=None):
    if img:
        try:
            response = client.delete_object(
            Bucket='my-bucket',
            Key='uploads/img.jpg',
            )
            print(response)
        except ClientError as ce:
            print("error", ce)
```

whenever i send a request to delete a certain file, I keep receiving error caught by exception:

**An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied**

I know it has something to do with my policies, i already set required policies to allow it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have full acces set for my IAM user for s3..
Or does it do something with bucket being **public?** or I am just missing something. Any suggestions will do, thanks for responding.

Comment: Where is code running, on an EC2 instance?

Comment: no in a backend api

Comment: That doesn't really say much. Where is the code running? A lambda function?

Comment: lets just say i have an api which accepts user image, uploads image, copy an object, deletes the old file...

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to share information with us

Comment: @Paolo, I have an api that accepts a file, and then upload to my bucket. Upload works, after that I have to delete an old object and this part right here calls the function, but this part here only calls the exception. I believe the other information isn't relevant because of the client error im receiving.

Comment: The fact that this code is part of an API is irrelevant. The place the code is running (Lambda, EC2, etc..) is the relevant part that you keep avoiding a clear answer to. A Lambda function or EC2 instance will have an IAM role assigned to it, and Boto3 will be picking up that IAM role and using it to make AWS API requests.

Comment: client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

api is running on localhost as of the moment.. Im using boto3's client to connect it to s3.

Comment: How does your code get AWS credentials? The policy that you've shown has a principal so it's a resource-based policy so it cannot be a policy associated with an IAM role that your code has assumed. Which resource is this policy attached to?

Answer (score 0):

The policy you have shown appears to be a **Bucket Policy** that is assigned to a *specific* bucket. This policy is granting **anyone in the world permission to use your S3 bucket**, so it is not recommended from a security viewpoint. You should remove this bucket policy.

You have mentioned that the provided code is running on "localhost" -- I will presume this means you are running it on your own computer.

In order to make API calls to AWS from that code, you will need to provide AWS credentials. Typically, these credentials are stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file by running the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. You would need to provide an Access Key and Secret Key associated with an **IAM User** (via the Security Credentials tab in the IAM management console).

You would then need to **assign permissions to the IAM User** so that they can use the S3 bucket. Note that the permissions are given to the **IAM User, not the bucket**:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The difference here is that there is no `Principal` because it is directly attached to the IAM User.

Comment: hi, John, thanks for your response.

yes, I am running currently in my localhost, in development.. (soon i will upload it to ec2 etc for hosting)
For this particular policy, you mentioned, This is direct policiy i need to add to my user in IAM?

and for security reasons, should i just leave my bucket policy empty?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It will give your IAM User permission to use the bucket, without giving permission to anybody else. When you move to an EC2 instance, put the policy on an **IAM Role** and then assign that role to the EC2 instance. It will work the same way. As for Bucket Policies, in general they should be used when granting public access to your bucket, but typically not when assigning permission to one entity (eg one IAM User).

Comment: If you store your credentials by using `aws configure`, you will be able to **remove the credentials from your code**. This is a much safer approach, since credentials can't be accidentally leaked in your code repository. So, just use: `client = boto3.client('s3')` Later, when using an IAM Role on the EC2 instance, the credentials will be automatically provided too.