# Django collectstatic ends up with "AWS S3 Boto3 Python - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied"

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Heroku+S3+Cloudfront and I'm facing the titled error when trying to collectstatic.
I'm having all the necessary IAM permissions, including AmazonS3FullAccess.
The django settings set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL=None.
My S3 bucket is configured with "Object Ownership" with "ACLs enabled" and it unblocks all public access (i.e. all set as public).

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my_bucket>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<my_stream>:distribution/<my_id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket CORs:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header"
        ]
    }
]
```

The closest case I found here is [AWS S3 Boto3 Python - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74669404/aws-s3-boto3-python-an-error-occurred-accessdenied-when-calling-the-deleteob) but it doesn't solve my issue...

I also tried extending the bucket policy with the following statement, but it didn't make any change..

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my_bucket>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks ahead